# No se aplica clase css al estar un input en focus con jquery

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo un input estoy usando bootstrap 3 para los css

```
<form>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Número de Filas:</label>
    <input type="text" id="no_filasVal" class="form-control">            
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Y tengo este codigo jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").focus(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("error");
    });
});
```

Clase "error" css:

```
.error { border-color: #FF0000; }
```

La pregunta aquí es porque cuando pongo en focus el input no aplica la clase css?? La aplica una vez que ese input no está en focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te hace falta el evento cuando se quita el `focus` del input, el `blur`:

```js
$("input").focus(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("error");
});
$("input").blur(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("error");
});
```

```css
.error {
  border-color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>Número de Filas:</label>
      <input type="text" id="no_filasVal" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Si le agregas `bootstrap` el estilo se deshabilita :( , pero se soluciona con un `!important` :)

Comment: No funciona, lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione ese input se aplique la clase css "error" para que pinte el borde de color rojo

Comment: @JorgeAlonso justo acaban de comentar que hy un problema con bootstrap

Comment: @ReneLimon asi lo pense

Comment: @JorgeAlonso entonces si te sirvió la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que al recibir el foco (seleccionar el input) se marque de rojo, no necesitas JavaScript, agrega esto:

```
#no_filasVal:focus { border-color: #FF0000 }
```

Yo en realidad crearía una clase utilitaria llamada `.red-on-focus` y listo

Espero te sirva de ayuda